# Checking if a non-list variable satisfies a predicate expression

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a predicate expression returning method called `GetPredicate` that I use for a list of users such as `return u => u.age == 30`, is there a better way to check if a single item `user1` satisfies this condition than doing this:

```
var validUser = (new List<User>(){ user1}).Where(GetPredicate()).SingleOrDefault();
```

Because this feels kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

A predicate is just a delegate that can be invoked like a regular method:

```
var validUser = GetPredicate()(user1);
```